# Best practice for developing site with openId - user table?

Tags: openid

I'm quite new to OpenId and I'm having a bit of a problem understanding how to use the OpenId once the authentication is complete.

I'm creating a new site, and I've had no problem in getting the openId authentication working. But I'm not sure how I should store user related data once the user is logged in.

Before openId, I would have my own registration process, a UserTable with a unique UserId (integer), and all other tables involving data related to some user activitiy would just have a UserId column identifying the user.

Should I now use the OpenId id in my tables? Should I create a really simple OpenId->UserId table that every login is mapped to and have data stored as previously? And what happens when a user want to use different OpenId providers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest that you have user id to `OpenID` mapping, just because it would make sense to have it one-to-many — it is a good practice to allow people have more than one `OpenID` identity bound to the account.

Comment: So I guess that when a user is authenticated, I should check my user table and see if the openId exists, if not create a new row...
But how do you (in a secure manner) allow people to map multiple OpenId to an existing userId?

Comment: Yes, actually, if the user comes with a yet unknown `OpenID` it would be the best to ask if the user wants to create a new account or bind it to the existing one (in the latter case user has to authenticate with the other OpenID).
As for secure way of managing OpenID — it is more or less UI thing. One of the solutions would be asking for confirmation after successfull `OpenID` roundtrip (or unsolicited identity assertion). The other would be to use a special nonce  or cookie for the roundtrip. Whatever you can come up with.

Answer (score 3):

I use two tables at my site:

1) Users - storing the user profile information

2) Credentials - storing user login information. Credentials may be different: {email, password/hash}, openID, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The Yahoo OpenID FAQ, http://developer.yahoo.com/openid/faq.html, has a great link to a recipe created by Joseph Smarr at Plaxo that details an adding OpenID to a web site that already has users, include DB table structure:

http://www.plaxo.com/api/openid_recipe

> This is a step-by-step tutorial guide for implementing OpenID
>   consumer-side support with a web site that already has users with
>   accounts. It will explain how to easily let new users sign up for an
>   account on your site using their OpenID URL and how to let existing
>   users attach their OpenID(s) so they can sign in using them.